# How to use SetColumnSpan?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am using the normal Grid, and adding Labels to from code, like tihs:

```
int a = 5;
Label lb = new Label();
lb.Content = a;

Grid.SetColumn(lb,i);
Grid.SetRow(lb, 1);
MyGrid.Children.Add(lb);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(lb,3);
```

The Label is added correctly to the Grid, but the columnspan is ineffective.Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: Show the whole code. Your construction should work.

Comment: Add some more data to the content and you will see that you did it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is ok. If you want to check this you should assign to the label content more data and grid property `ShowGridLines` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.showgridlines.aspx)) set to true.

Example:

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid" ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

code-behind:

```
Label lb = new Label();
lb.Content = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890";

Grid.SetColumn(lb, 1);
Grid.SetRow(lb, 1);
MyGrid.Children.Add(lb);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(lb, 3);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You are right, thanks! GridLines were visible, that's why I thought the spanning did not work.